# Python-FTP download all files in directory

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm putting together a script to download all the files from a directory via FTP. So far I have managed to connect and fetch one file, but I cannot seem to make to work in batch (get all the files from the directory) Here is what I have so far:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os, sys, os.path

def handleDownload(block):
    file.write(block)
    print ".",

ddir='C:\\Data\\test\\'
os.chdir(ddir)
ftp = FTP('test1/server/')

print 'Logging in.'
ftp.login('user1\\anon', 'pswrd20')
directory = '\\data\\test\\'

print 'Changing to ' + directory
ftp.cwd(directory)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')

print 'Accessing files'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files: 
        full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname);  
        print 'Opening local file ' 
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR C:\\Data\\test\\' + fname,
                       handleDownload,
                       open(full_fname, 'wb'));
        print 'Closing file ' + filename
        file.close();
ftp.close()
```

I bet you can tell that it does not do much when I run it, so any suggestions for improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 78):

I've managed to crack this, so now posting the relevant bit of code for future visitors:

```
filenames = ftp.nlst() # get filenames within the directory
print filenames

for filename in filenames:
    local_filename = os.path.join('C:\\test\\', filename)
    file = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)

    file.close()

ftp.quit() # This is the “polite” way to close a connection
```

This worked for me on Python 2.5, Windows XP.

Comment: The recommended way is to use: `ftp.quit()` instead of `ftp.close()`.
Please [see this link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.quit)

Comment: How does ftp.nlst() know which link I want? This answer seems to be incomplete.

Comment: wont work if you have a directory name in the ```filenames``` list

Answer (score 11):

If this is just a problem you'd like to solve, I might suggest the `wget` command:

```
cd c:\destination
wget --mirror --continue --no-host-directories --user=username --password=s3cr3t ftp://hostname/source/path/
```

The `--continue` option could be very dangerous if files *change* on the server. If files are only ever *added*, then it is very friendly.

However, if this is a learning exercise for you and you'd like to make your program work, I think you should start by looking at this line:

> ```
> for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
> ```

`directory` has been the *remote* source directory in most of your program, but the `os.walk()` function cannot walk a *remote* directory. You need to iterate over the returned files yourself, using a callback supplied to the [`retrlines`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) function.

Take a look at the `MLSD` or `NLST` options instead of `LIST`, they will probably be easier to parse. (Note that FTP doesn't actually specify how lists should look; it was always intended to be driven by a human at a console, or a specific filename transferred. So programs that do clever things with FTP listings like present them to the user in a GUI probably have to have huge piles of special case code, for odd or obscure servers. And they probably all do something stupid when faced with malicious file names.)

Can you use [`sftp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) instead? `sftp` *does* have a specification for how file listings are supposed to be parsed, doesn't transmit username/password in the clear, and doesn't have the giant annoyance of passive vs active connections -- it simply uses the single connection, which means it works across more firewalls than FTP does.

**Edit**: You need to pass a 'callable' object to the `retrlines` function. A callable object is either an instance of a class that defined a `__call__` method, or a function. While the function might be easier to describe, an instance of a class may be more useful. (You could use the instance to collect the filenames, but the function would have to write to a global variable. Bad.)

Here's one of the simplest callable object:

```
>>> class c:
...  def __call__(self, *args):
...   print(args)
...
>>> f = c()
>>> f('hello')
('hello',)
>>> f('hello', 'world')
('hello', 'world')
```

This creates a new class, `c`, that defines an instance method `__call__`. This just prints its arguments in a fairly stupid manner, but it shows how minimal we're talking. :)

If you wanted something smarter, it could do something like this:

```
class handle_lines:
  def __init__(self):
    self.lines = []
  def __call__(self, *args):
    self.lines << args[0]
```

Call `iterlines` with an object of this class, then look in the object's `lines` member for details.

Comment: @Sosti, the `retrlines` function mention in my post is a hyperlink off to the documentation :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, they all sound like solid suggestions! I forgot to mention i m using Python 2.5 on Windows XP (if that s useful at all) If I use the MLSD option, 'ftp.retrlines('MLSD')', would the code work for the iteration or do I need to modify more? (sure it sounds a bit daft but newb here, remember?:DD)

Comment: @Sosti, you would still need to modify your code: you can't use the `os.walk()` function. I'll edit my answer in a bit to show how to make a callback object for `retrlines`.

Comment: I have to admit I need to do some research on this, and attempt to write some lines of code. I was hoping the problem could be fixed by tweaking some lines but apparently the issue is more fundamental. Will do my best and then come back with any results. Thanks for all the input and suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

this code is a little bit of overkill I think.

(from the python example https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) After ftp.login() and setting ftp.cwd() you can just use:

```
os.chdir(ddir)
ls = ftp.nlst()
count = len(ls)
curr = 0
print "found {} files".format(count)
for fn in ls:
    curr += 1
    print 'Processing file {} ... {} of {} ...'.format(fn, curr, count)
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fn, open(fn, 'wb').write)

ftp.quit()
print "download complete."
```

to download all the files.

Comment: Going a bit forward, is it possible to check hash before writing out? on the FTP server I try to download there's `file1.gz` and `file1.gz.md5` and so on , the remote has more than 1200 files so it is not possible to download all and check (memory problem)

Answer (score 1):

A recursive solution (py 2.7):

```
import os, ftplib, shutil, operator

def cloneFTP((addr, user, passw), remote, local):
    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(addr)
        ftp.login(user, passw)
        ftp.cwd(remote)
    except: 
        try: ftp.quit()
        except: pass
        print 'Invalid input ftp data!'
        return False
    try: shutil.rmtree(local)
    except: pass
    try: os.makedirs(local)
    except: pass
    dirs = []
    for filename in ftp.nlst():
        try:
            ftp.size(filename)
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, open(os.path.join(local, filename), 'wb').write)
        except:
            dirs.append(filename)
    ftp.quit()
    res = map(lambda d: cloneFTP((addr, user, passw), os.path.join(remote, d), os.path.join(local, d)), dirs)
    return reduce(operator.iand, res, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner so I have not made the code efficiently but I made it and tested it is working. This is what I did to download files and folders from ftp site but only limited depth in file structure.

```
try:
   a = input("Enter hostname : ")
   b = input("Enter username : ")
   c = input("Enter password : ")
   from ftplib import FTP
   import os
   os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp")
   os.chdir("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp")
   ftp = FTP(host = a, user= b, passwd = c)
   D = ftp.nlst()
   for d in D:
      l = len(d)
      char = False
      for i in range(0,l):
          char = char or d[i]=="."
      if not char:
         ftp.cwd("..")
         ftp.cwd("..")
         E = ftp.nlst("%s"%(d))
         ftp.cwd("%s"%(d))
         try:
             os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp\\%s"%(d))
         except:
             print("you can debug if you try some more")
         finally:
             os.chdir("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp\\%s"%(d))
             for e in E:
                l1 = len(e)
                char1 = False
                for i in range(0,l1):
                   char1 = char1 or e[i]=="."
                if not char1:
                   ftp.cwd("..")
                   ftp.cwd("..")
                   F = ftp.nlst("%s/%s"%(d,e))
                   ftp.cwd("%s/%s"%(d,e))
                   try:
                       os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp\\%s\\%s"%(d,e))
                   except:
                       print("you can debug if you try some more")
                   finally:
                       os.chdir("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp\\%s\\%s"%(d,e))
                       for f in F:
                           if "." in f[2:]:
                               with open(f,'wb') as filef:
                                   ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %(f), filef.write)
                           elif not "." in f:
                               try:
                                  os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp\\%s\\%s\\%s"%(d,e,f))
                               except:
                                  print("you can debug if you try some more")
                elif "." in e[2:]:
                   os.chdir("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp\\%s"%(d))
                   ftp.cwd("..")
                   ftp.cwd("..")
                   ftp.cwd("..")
                   ftp.cwd("%s"%(d))
                   with open(e,'wb') as filee:
                      ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %(e), filee.write)
      elif "." in d[2:]:
          ftp.cwd("..")
          ftp.cwd("..")
          os.chdir("C:\\Users\\PREM\\Desktop\\pyftp download\\ftp")
          with open(d,'wb') as filed:
             ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s'%(d), filed.write)
   ftp.close()
   print("Your files has been successfully downloaded and saved. Bye")
except:
    print("try again you can do it")
finally:
    print("code ran")
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11704863)

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using Python lib to ftp download a directory, we can call a dos script from python program. In the dos script we would use the native ftp protocol which can download all file from the folder using `mget *.*`.

```
fetch.bat
ftp -s:fetch.txt

fetch.txt
open <ipaddress>
<userid>
<password>
bin (set the mnode to binary)
cd </desired directory>
mget *.*
bye

fetch.py
import os
os.system("fetch.bat")
```

Comment: it is also specific to windows (dos)

Comment: Sometimes, it helps.