# download zipfile from a ftp link

Tags: python, ftp, zip, python-requests

I'm trying to download a zip file from an FTP link. I've tried to use request package but could not download

```
import requests
url = 'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Precos_Indices_de_Precos_ao_Consumidor/IPCA/Serie_Historica/ipca_SerieHist.zip'
r = requests.get(url)
```

Is there an easy way to download it? I can download it from the Chrome and don't need any type of login and password
Thanks

Comment: "could not download" ... what, exactly, went wrong? Don't leave us guessing!

Comment: `requests` doesn't support FTP and its error message is more than a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this answer out: [Python download zip files from a public FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710459/python-download-zip-files-from-a-public-ftp-server) The answer in that is below, credit  to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4582273/lemonhead

```
url = urlparse.urlparse("ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Precos_Indices_de_Precos_ao_Consumidor/IPCA/Serie_Historica/ipca_SerieHist.zip")
ftp = ftplib.FTP(url.netloc)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd(ftp_dirname)
# Directory it will be downloaded to ^

with open(filename, 'w') as fobj:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % basename, fobj.write)
```

Comment: This is close but needs some cleanup, like `ftp_dirname`

Comment: Is that better? Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Do not copy answers to duplicate questions. Vote the question to be closed as duplicate instead.